# Simplephp and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I’m simply iterating through nodes and adding the name of the node to an array but it is creating it as multidimensional array instead of one dimensional.

```
$arrayname[] = attribute[‘name’];
```

How do I get this to build as a one dimensional array? I need it this way as I’m checking to see if a value exists before adding it using in_array.

Right now I get

```
[0] SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [0] => bob

)
```

Comment: Write the xml file

Comment: More data is needed in order to understand your issue - does the `$attribute` array is XML? what is you desire output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement`s have to be cast to string type to use as a string. Change your code to this (assuming your attributes array is `$attribute`):

```
$arrayname[] = (string)$attribute[‘name’];
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. I spent hours trying to figure this one out. I appreciate it.